# How to execute an SQL script stored in S3 other than datapipeline service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have been working on leveraging AWS services for scheduling few sql scripts on a daily basis. Datapipeline is a good option but we have found issues with underlying support systems which is Task runner. Is there any other options that we can look for. The Lambda has a limitation of 300 seconds. And the query which we are using will exceed 5 minutes. Any suggestions/workarounds is much appreciated.!!

Comment: What do you mean by "few sql scripts"? Are you just doing some reporting, or are you moving data (like an ETL job)? If it is just reporting, you could use **Amazon Athena**. If it is ETL, you could use **AWS Glue**.

Comment: John,It would be rather one - two scripts which has to be executed on a specific time of the day. Our focus is on the scheduling part mainly and how we can do it other than datapipeline. Glue seems to be bit expensive for this small piece of work. Could you suggest anything better or should we go outside AWS enviornment like a thirdparty software.

Comment: Your question provides very little information to be of assistance. Feel free to edit the question and provide more information. For example, what do the scripts do — are they computationally heavy, or do they just run a few statements on a database (which one)? Do they transport data from one system to another? Does execution time vary by the amount of data or the amount of changes since last execution (which will impact scalability)? With more information, we can give you a better answer.

Comment: Sure.,The script is computationally medium and it checks certain conditions and stamps the satisfied records. The volume of records affected each day may vary and it can definitely run beyond 10 minutes and is purely dependent on new data which has an increasing trend. There is no transportation of data involved. Please let me know if we can leverage any AWS service s other than  datapipeline to implement this or outside of AWS should be seeked.

Comment: We'd need much more information about what you're doing to provide good suggestions of how to process your workload. However, the basic options are Lambda or EC2 (and there are several ways to trigger EC2, such as Data Pipeline). Frankly, you could probably just launch a Linux EC2 instance each day with a User Data script, then terminate it when it is finished. EC2 with Linux is charged per-second, so it's quite reasonably priced.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path. Use Lambda just to kick off the job, not to do the actual workload.

For example, pack your app in a Docker container, push it to ECR and use Lambdas to periodically add an AWS Batch job.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sergey, This is quite an information. Let me try this out.